# When creating new CMD process exe not found" 'DisplaySwitch' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: c#

When I run command `DisplaySwitch 4` in CMD directly, it works perfectly, but when I run the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\MyUsername",
};

Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("DisplaySwitch 4");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();

// Read the output and error streams if needed
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

// Wait for the process to exit
process.WaitForExit();

// Display the output and error
Console.WriteLine("Output:");
Console.WriteLine(output);

Console.WriteLine("\nError:");
Console.WriteLine(error);
```

I always get the following error:

`'DisplaySwitch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Why does it not work in such case?

Comment: Run "where displayswitch.exe" to find out where it is located.  I'd guess you see it in c:\windows\system32 but not in c:\windows\syswow64, so when your program runs in 32-bit mode it won't find it.

Comment: It is indeed located in `C:\Windows\System32\`. So should I run it as 64bit if 32bit won't find it?

Comment: You should always prefer 64-bit today.

Comment: It works! 64-bit did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to both Mad hatter and Hans Passant.
The solution, as credited to Hans Passant, was to set x64 platform for running the program.

And the improvement, as credited to Mat hatter, ended up being as following:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = @"DisplaySwitch.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = false,
    RedirectStandardError = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = argument
};

Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "DisplaySwitch.exe",
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\MyUsername",
    Arguments = "4"
};
```

Comment: It doesn't find the file, even if I put it as `FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe"`

Comment: I've launched this from an app targeting 'Any CPU', with option "Prefer 32 bits" unchecked.

Comment: Yes, the solution is to set the platform to x64.

Comment: When checking the option I reproduce totally your issue ^^'. Nice catch.

Comment: Wonderful improvement to my code though!